# JavaScript and Node.js RESTful web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications

I've been doing a lot of research because I would like to create a web application using JavaScript and Node.js with an SQL back-end, but I'm getting really confused. There are so many different frameworks and tools out there and I've found some and tried some that I would really like to use, but I just don't know how to use them all together in 1 project. Some are client-side, some are server-side, some are both and for some I'm not even sure.

Could it be possible to use all of the following frameworks/tools in 1 project in a sensible way?

**Client side:**

- jQuery
- Bootstrap

**Server side:**

- ExpressJS (I like it being RESTful)

**Other tools:**

- Grunt (JSHint task, automated testing, ...)
- QUnit (Is this only a client side testing framework? Are there server side testing frameworks?)

Comment: you can use mentioned tools above and I suggest you to use `sequelize` for ORM!

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this existed! I really think I could use this

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

In Express interact with databases, build business logic, expose API routes.

Your client side files could be served by Express or anything else (nginx, apache, whatever).  jQuery can be used to call your Express API, though I would recommend Angular or Backbone for larger projects.

Grunt can be used for host of automated tasks such as concat files for production, run tests, reload server. (I prefer Gulp.js)

For testing see mocha, karma, or do google search and find plenty of others.

I enjoy [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) and think it is a great framework to learn on.  Here are some example apps for it [link](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-examples)

If you have your client side served from a different domain you will need to read about CORS.

Do some more research there are tons of other answered questions and resources on this already.

Check out Yeoman.io for generators that will setup the structure for a variety of apps.

Comment: Would you say Grunt is a Client-side or Server-side tool? And is QUnit only for testing client side code or for both client and server side?

Comment: And how would you go about organizing such a project? Could you possibly give me an example?

Comment: Grunt runs on the server, but can be used to build both server and client side files.  QUnit can be used on server side javascript, but I think you will find those specifically built for server side javscript to be more robust in that area.  I am putting together a tutorial, but am currently slammed so it will be a while. There are loads of resources already out there though. Again spend some more time searching.  "express bootstrap example" is sure to have plenty of results.